# Show that $\log(x)$ is a Bounded Mean Oscillation (BMO)

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

As an extension of our class notes, we were asked to show that the function $w =\log(x)$ is a Bounded Mean Oscillation (BMO).

First off, I believe our professor made a mistake, and really wanted us to show that $w = \log|x|$ was a BMO, just to keep everything real.

That being said, by the John-Nirenburg Lemma, a function $w$ is a bounded mean oscillation (BMO) if $\displaystyle \frac{1}{|B_{r}|}\int_{B_{r}}|w-\overline{w}_{B_{r}}|\leq C$, where $B_{r}$ is a ball of radius $r$, $\displaystyle \overline{w}_{B_{r}}$ is the average value of $w$ over the ball of radius $r$ (so $\displaystyle \overline{w}_{B_{r}}$ can also be written as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{|B_{r}|}\int_{B_{r}}|w|$), and $C$ is a constant.

I would like to do and understand this exercise, but so far, all I've been able to do is set it up.  I figured that since $\displaystyle w = \log|x|$, then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{|B_{r}|}\int_{B_{r}}\left|\,\log|x|-\frac{1}{|B_{r}|}\int_{B_{r}}\log|x|\, \right|$.

I'm not sure how to manipulate this expression in order to show that it is $\leq C$.  Should I add and subtract some quantities? Should I try to introduce some exponentials?  I think the two integrals are tripping me up a bit, as well.  So, any suggestions and/or assistance you could offer would be much appreciated :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I imagine your professor expects the definition of BMO for a function not defined on all of $\Bbb R$ is that the mean oscillation is bounded on the domain, so $\log x$ is BMO iff $\log|x|$ is.

Comment: Fair enough. In any case, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nice thing about the interaction between $\log x$ and that expression is that they are both scale-invariant, which allows us to eliminate one of the degrees of freedom. To be precise, suppose the boundaries of the ball are $(xy,x)$ where $x>0$ and $0<y<1$. Then:

\begin{align}
\bar w(x,y)&=\frac1{x(1-y)}\int_{xy}^x\log t\, dt\\
&=\frac1{1-y}\int_y^1(\log u+\log x)\, du=\bar w(1,y)+\log x\\
MO(x,y)&=\frac1{x(1-y)}\int_{xy}^x\left|\log t-\bar w(x,y)\right|\,dt\\
&=\frac1{1-y}\int_y^1\left|\log u+\log x-\bar w(x,y)\right|\,du\\
&=\frac1{1-y}\int_y^1\left|\log u-\bar w(1,y)\right|\,du=MO(1,y)
\end{align}

Now that everything is only in terms of $y$, let's just do the integral:

$$\bar w(1,y)=\frac1{1-y}\int_y^1\log t\, dt=\frac{y\log y-y+1}{y-1}$$

$$MO(1,y)=\frac1{1-y}\int_y^1\left|\log t-\frac{y\log y-y+1}{y-1}\right|\,dt$$

Since $\log x$ is an increasing function, we can expect this integrand to have two regions. Left of the critical point $t_0$ such that $\log t=\frac{y\log y-y+1}{y-1}$, the function will look like $-\log t$, and to the right of $t_0$, it will look like $\log t$ (but shifted vertically). The right side is easy to bound: the integrand is bounded by $1$:

$$\log t-\frac{y\log y-y+1}{y-1}\le\frac{y\log y}{1-y}+1\le1,$$

because $x\log x<0$ for $x\in(0,1)$. The left side is unbounded, but we can use a simple trick to bound the value of the integral. By definition, the mean value $\bar w$ is chosen so that the areas under the left part and the right part are equal; but we have just shown that the area of the right part is at most $1\cdot(1-t_0)\le1-y$, so the total area under the function must be at most $2(1-y)$, and so $MO(1,y)=MO(x,y)\le2$.

Comment: The maple code $$Optimization:-Maximize((int(abs(ln(t)-(y*ln(y)+y-1)/(1-y)), t = y .. 1))/(1-y), y = 0 .. 1)  $$ outputs $$[ 1.99999998945488788,[y= 0.99999998945488822]]  .$$

Comment: @user64494 Indeed, I highly expect the least bound on $MO(x,y)$ to be $2$, because I roughly double the estimate by using a constant bound for a nearly linear function (note that $\log x$ becomes linear as $y\to1$). However, it suffices to prove any bound, and $4$ is as good as any.

Comment: @ Mario Carneiro : I demonstrate not a better estimate, but the way to obtain such estimate numerically.

Comment: @Mario: For $w(1, y)$ shouldn't we have \begin{align}w(1, y)&=\frac{1}{1-y}\left\{\left[t\log t\right]_{y}^{1}-\int_y^1\ \mathrm{d}t\right\}\\ &= \frac{-y\log y- (1-y)}{1-y}\end{align}

Comment: For $t_0$ in your soln, if $0>c\equiv\log t_0\equiv \frac{-y \log y+y-1}{1-y}$ then my understanding is that $c$ is such that\begin{equation}\int_{y}^{t_0}c-\log t\ \mathrm{d}t=\int_{t_0}^1 \log t-c\ \mathrm{d}t.\end{equation} However, we find that \begin{align}LHS &= (t_0-y)c-[t\log t]_{y}^{t_0}+ (t_0-y)\\ RHS &= -(1-t_0)c+[t\log t]_{t_0}^1+(1-t_0).\end{align} Then\begin{equation} LHS-RHS= 2(t_0-1)=0\Leftrightarrow t_0=1 \end{equation} but $t_0\neq 1$ correct?

Comment: @Nirav For your first comment, you are correct about the sign error, and it seems to affect the results significantly. (I was plotting graphs as I went, but now they don't make as much sense as they did when I wrote this...) I will update the answer. As for your other comment, I don't see how you are getting that last expression - when I work it out I get $$LHS-RHS=(1+c)(1-y)+y\log y,$$ and setting that equal to zero gives $c=\frac{-y\log y+y-1}{1-y}$ as expected.

Comment: @Mario: I've seen my error. I should have \begin{equation} RHS=-(1-t_0)c+[t\log t]_{t_0}^1-(1-t_0) \end{equation} which then implies that \begin{equation} LHS-RHS=c(1-y)+y\log y -y+1 =0 \end{equation} which is what we want.

Comment: @Mario The RHS is still bounded though: \begin{equation} \int_{t_0}^1 \log t-c \mathrm{d}t\leq -c(1-t_0)\end{equation} because $\log t<0$ and $-c>0$. Further, \begin{equation} -c=\frac{y \log y +1-y }{1-y}\leq 1\end{equation} because $\frac{y \log y}{1-y}<0$, and consequently, $LHS=RHS\leq (1-t_0)$. Thus, \begin{equation} \frac{1}{1-y}\int_{y}^1 |\log t-c|\ \mathrm{d}t\leq 2.\end{equation}

Comment: @Nival Yes, the argument is actually a bit easier now than it was, and the same general observations apply (and the bound is down from 4 to 2).

Comment: Sorry for my late comment, could you kindly tell me why ''the mean value is chosen so that the areas under the left part and the right part are equal''？

Comment: @Steve It's a bit of geometry. If you compare a function to the constant function that is its average value on an interval, the area above the line will equal the area below the line. It's fairly easy to check this formally: the integral of the difference, $\int_a^b f(x)-\bar f\,dx$, is 0 by virtue of the definition $\bar f=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, oh I got it! Thanks for your patience and help!