# The relation between BMO and bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

When studying BMO ([bounded mean oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation)), it makes me think of its relation with [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation). These two both describe some kind of oscillation. However, it is quite different, e.x. bounded function is BMO, I want to know if there is relation with these two

Answer (score 2):

$$BV(\mathbb R)\subsetneq BMO(\mathbb R)$$

The inclusion follows easily by noting that $BV$ functions are bounded. There are cheap examples showing the inclusion must be strict, like $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto \sin(x).$ A more interesting example is the function defined a.e. by $f(x)=\log |x|.$ It's in $BMO(\mathbb R)$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773645/show-that-logx-is-a-bounded-mean-oscillation-bmo?rq=1)) even though its restriction to $(0,b)$ is not in $L^\infty(0,b)$ for any $b>0.$

For higher dimensions the two spaces are incomparable. The function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\log|x_1|$ is in $BMO(\mathbb R^n)\setminus BV(\mathbb R^n).$ Let $\phi$ be some smooth function with $\phi(0)=1$ and rapid decay at infinity e.g. $\phi(r)=e^{-r^2}.$ Then the function defined by $f(x)=|x|^{-1/2}\phi(|x|)$ is in $W^{1,1}(\mathbb R^n)\subset BV(\mathbb R^n)$ but not in $BMO(\mathbb R^n).$